# Visual Studio 2017 + Xamarin intellisense is stuck in Android mode

Tags: xamarin, intellisense, visual-studio-2017

I created an SAP project with Android and iOS legs.  Use `#if __IOS__` and `#if __ANDROID__` for platform specific code.  Intellisense shows the code under `#if __IOS__` as "gray comment" (and `#if __ANDROID__` as normal code), even if I switch to iOS by choosing the iOS leg a StartUp Project.  The code actually compiles in iOS, but that has no effect on intellisense.

Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a combobox at the top of the Text Editor in VS where you can select which project you're "viewing":

[image: Text Editor in Visual Studio]

It contains the projects that include the current file. With iOS selected, my iOS code has color and I get Intellisense functionality. With WPF selected, iOS code is grayed out and Intellisense is disabled within that block.

FYI, here is my Solution Explorer:

[image: Solution Explorer]